# How do I obtain the count of objects of values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am adding key/value pairs to a dictionary, the `keys` are characters from a-z, the `values` are character triplets, such as `'aba'`, `'afa'`, `'fgf'`, etc.

So after this, my dictionary may look like this:

`my_dict = {'a': {'aaa', 'aba'}, 'b': {'bbb', 'bcb', 'bpb'}}`

Now, I want to print the total count of the values. (In the above example, it is 5). How do I do this?

When I do `print(len(my_dict.values())`, it produces 2 as the output (the number of elements), which is not what I am after.

Comment: Iterate through the dict, call Len on each entry and sum the results.

Comment: `sum(map(len, my_dict.values()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
n_total = sum(len(v) for v in my_dict.values())
```

This iterates over the values of your dictionary and sums up their [lengths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) (assuming the values represent sequences or collections). By the way, this makes use of [generator expression](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/).

Calling [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) is equivalent, but about twice as fast as it avoids some overhead related to generator expressions.

```py
n_total = sum(map(len, my_dict.values()))
```

Both options are more pythonic and faster than an explicit loop:

```py
def count_len(seq):
    count = 0
    for elm in seq:
        count += len(elm)
    return count

n_total = count_len(my_dict.values())
```

---

To compare the performance, you can run the following commands in an IPython session. I initialized the dictionary using `random` as follows:

```
import random
import string
n = 100000
triplet_gen = lambda: "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=3))
my_dict = { i: set(triplet_gen() for _ in range(random.randint(0,5))) for i in range(n)}

%timeit sum(len(v) for v in my_dict.values())
%timeit sum(map(len, my_dict.values()))
%timeit count_values(my_dict)
```